# How to apply sorting with paging?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sorting, pagination

I tried applying sorting with paging but it is only sorting first page because the page number is one which is fine by me but the records of second and third page are not sorted.

Here is the FIRST PAGE CODE

```
include_once("session.php");
include_once("functions.php");
include_once("connection.php");

$username = $_SESSION["username"];


$orderby = "job_name";
$order = "asc";
//$conn2 = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","jobportal");
//$conn3 = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","jobportal");
//$conn4 = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","jobportal");


$sql3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM job_info WHERE username='$username' AND approved=1";
$sql4 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM job_info WHERE username='$username' AND approved=0";

$stmt3 = $conn->query($sql3);
$stmt4 = $conn->query($sql4);
$approved = $stmt3->fetch_array();
$pending = $stmt4->fetch_array();

$total_rows_approved = $approved[0];
$total_rows_pending = $pending[0];

$limit = 2;
$total_pages_apporved = ceil($total_rows_approved/$limit);
$total_pages_pending = ceil($total_rows_pending/$limit);
$page_approved = 0;
$page_pending = 0;
if(isset($_GET["page_approved"])){
    $page_approved = $_GET["page_approved"];
}
if($page_approved){
    $start_approved = ($page_approved-1)*$limit;
}
else{
    $start_approved = 0;
}

if(isset($_GET["page_pending"])){
    $page_pending = $_GET["page_pending"];
}
if($page_pending){
    $start_pending = ($page_pending-1)*$limit;
}
else{
    $start_pending = 0;
}

$sql1 = "select * from job_info where username='$username' and approved=1 order by ".$orderby." ".$order." limit $start_approved,$limit";
$stmt1 = $conn->query($sql1);

$sql2 = "select * from job_info where username='$username' and approved=0 order by ".$orderby." ".$order." limit $start_pending,$limit";
$stmt2 = $conn->query($sql2);

<script>
    var page_no_approved=1;
    var page_no_pending=1;
    function order_column1(column_name,column_order){
        $.ajax({
        url: "get_job_list.php",
        data: "orderby1="+column_name+"&order1="+column_order+"&page_no_approved="+page_no_approved,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            $("#showresults").html(data);
       }
    });
}
function order_column2(column_name,column_order){

    $.ajax({
    url: "get_job_list.php",
    data: "orderby2="+column_name+"&order2="+column_order+"&page_no_pending="+page_no_pending,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data){
        $("#showresults").html(data);
    }
    });
}
</script>
```

and here is the SECOND PAGE CODE(ajax)

```
include_once("session.php");
include_once("functions.php");
include_once("connection.php");

$username = $_SESSION["username"];

$sql3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM job_info WHERE username='$username' AND approved=1";
$sql4 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM job_info WHERE username='$username' AND approved=0";

$stmt3 = $conn->query($sql3);
$stmt4 = $conn->query($sql4);
$approved = $stmt3->fetch_array();
$pending = $stmt4->fetch_array();

$total_rows_approved = $approved[0];
$total_rows_pending = $pending[0];

$limit = 2;
$total_pages_apporved = ceil($total_rows_approved/$limit);
$total_pages_pending = ceil($total_rows_pending/$limit);
$page_approved = 0;
$page_pending = 0;
if(isset($_POST["page_no_approved"])){
    $page_approved = $_POST["page_no_approved"];
}
if($page_approved){
    $start_approved = ($page_approved-1)*$limit;
}
else{
    $start_approved = 0;
}

if(isset($_POST["page_no_pending"])){
    $page_pending = $_POST["page_no_pending"];
}
if($page_pending){
    $start_pending = ($page_pending-1)*$limit;
}
else{
    $start_pending = 0;
}

$orderby1 = "job_name";
$order1 = "asc";
$orderby2 = "job_name";
$order2 = "asc";

if(!empty($_POST["orderby1"])){
    $orderby1 = $_POST["orderby1"];
}
if(!empty($_POST["order1"])){
    $order1 = $_POST["order1"];
}

if(!empty($_POST["orderby2"])){
    $orderby2 = $_POST["orderby2"];
}
if(!empty($_POST["order2"])){
    $order2 = $_POST["order2"];
}

$date_order1 = "asc";
$job_name_order1 = "asc";
$industry_order1 = "asc";
$date_order2 = "asc";
$job_name_order2 = "asc";
$industry_order2 = "asc";

if($orderby1 == "date" && $order1=="asc"){
    $date_order1 = "desc";
}
if($orderby1 == "job_name" && $order1=="asc"){
    $job_name_order1 = "desc";
}
if($orderby1 == "industry" && $order1 == "asc"){
    $industry_order1 = "desc";
}
if($orderby2 == "date" && $order2=="asc"){
    $date_order2 = "desc";
}
if($orderby2 == "job_name" && $order2=="asc"){
    $job_name_order2 = "desc";
}
if($orderby2 == "industry" && $order2 == "asc"){
    $industry_order2 = "desc";
}

$sql1 = "select * from job_info where username='$username' and approved=1 order by ".$orderby1." ".$order1." limit $start_approved,$limit";
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

$sql2 = "select * from job_info where username='$username' and approved=0 order by ".$orderby2." ".$order2." limit $start_pending,$limit";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
```

EDIT: I didn't included the code to display data because it will make the already large code to be more longer and possibly unreadable. It would help if someone could point me to the place where the concept of sorting with pagination is applied or if someone could explain the concept with small example.

Comment: Where do you return any data to the client? Have you printed out the sql statements for debugging purposes? Have you checked for sql errors? Have you checked for php errors? In short: have you done any debugging at all?

Comment: Btw your code is at risk of sql injection attacks.

Comment: @Shadow I didn't included the code to display data because it would have made the code very large and cumbersome.

Comment: @Shadow Could you please tell me where is the code at risk of sql injection.

Comment: All sql statements assembled using input parameters received ftom the client without any escaping or prepared statement without parameters are at risk of sql injection. Be aware that simple escaping is not enough to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Your sql code queries your data in an ordered way. You should test that on the server side. Your display logic may interfere with the ordering of the code. You need to do the debugging, we can't help with these.

Comment: @Shadow I just need to know the concept when applying sorting with pagination if there is some link it would help.

Comment: 1. Asking for off-site resource is off-topic on SO. 2. There is nothing obviously wrong with your sorting and paging. This is why you need to do some debugging so you can narrow down where the error occurs and share only that piece of code with us.

Comment: @Shadow The problem is that pagination is applied separately to sorting; sorting is applied in second page ajax code where page no is always one so it is only fetching $limit records from $start which is 2 and 0 respectively but if I click at page number 2 or 3 the page is refreshed and only those records are fetched which meet the criteria of $start,$limit all this because pagination is applied in first page.That's where I am stuck because I am not getting how to apply pagination with sorting..

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cant't follow. You do apply sorting in the 2nd set of code as well.

Comment: @Shadow Pagination in first page, page is refreshed every-time a new page number is clicked. Sorting in second page using ajax.